Lower bound of integral operator in $L^{\infty}$
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures, and consider the operator (supposed well-defined) $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ to $L^{\infty}(\nu)$ by $Tg(y) = \int T(x,y)g(x) \mu(dx)$ where the kernel $T(x,y) \geq 0$. Under what conditions on the kernel is the operator uniformly lower bounded : $\|Tg\|_{L^{\infty}(\nu)} \geq \delta \|g\|_{L^{\infty}(\mu)}$ for some $\delta > 0$?

Do you mean $Tg(y) = \int T(x,y) g(x)\mu(dx)$? Or otherwise, how does your definition involve $g$?

Yes! Sorry for the mistake

Can I also ask, what kind of lower bound are you looking for? A pointwise lower bound is hopeless, since $g\equiv 0$ results in $Tg \equiv 0$.

@user1149748  : $|Tg|{L^{\infty}(\nu)} \geq \delta |g|{L^{\infty}(\mu)}$ for $\delta > 0$

This lower bound implies the closedness of the range of $T$, hence $T$ cannot be compact.

For Banach, a compact operator is closed range iff its range space is of finite dimension. So it can be compact, or not here
